# Remove default flags on cmake

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, flags

The following `CMakeLists.txt`

```
 SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/DWIN32")
 SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
 add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
```

ends up running

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W1 /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"hello.dir\Release\\" /Fd"C:/Users/monso/code/playground/cmakeworld/build/Release /hello.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue ..\hello.cpp
```

with flags `/c /nologo /W1 /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG`.

How can I remove them to put my own? setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` appends any flag I put (`/w` for example). While printing `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` before and after the `set` call does change its values.

Comment: It looks like some basic flags are always added by CMake.  There isn't a way to remove them short of replacing them with a different option for the same flag (e.g. setting `/W0` to get rid of `/W1`).

Comment: @Fraser Wah, it seems such a basic and simple feature to me. Well, ok. No success then. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5):

CMake uses distinct variables for each build type. They are called `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<BUILDTYPE>` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_<BUILDTYPE>`

So, for CXX, this would be

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
```

**Additionally**, it uses the settings in the "general" variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`

So in order to get rid of the defaults, you would need to set the global or specific variable and clear the other one (or configure them as you need).

*Note:* If you want those changes in the cache, you need to use the `FORCE` parameter. Otherwise, they are locally employed to this project and its child projects.

Answer (score -1):

use set_target_property.

```
add_executable(help
               helpMe.cpp
)
get_target_property(LOVE PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS)
message("Target Compiler flags are: ${MAIN_CFLAGS}")

set_target_properties(LOVE PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "")
get_target_property(LOVE PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS)
message("Target Compiler flags are: ${MAIN_CFLAGS}")
```

it will work.